# After I True Polymorph myself and concentrate for the full duration, how can I get back to my normal form?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

After 1 hour of concentration on the True Polymorph spell, the transformation lasts until it is dispelled.

If the target is myself, how can I get back to my normal form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've literally stated the answer in your question and it's in True Polymorph's description.

> The transformation lasts until it is dispelled.

If someone casts Dispel Magic on you then you get transformed back into yourself.

Comment: Could you add a citation of the errata? In the earlier printings the spell did not specify "until dispelled" so it might create confusion without sourcing.

Comment: @Odo: The issue is that as far as I can tell, the [PHB errata PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) doesn't actually note the change explicitly (though other changes to the spell are noted there). The latest version of the spell description can be seen here: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph

Comment: *Successfully* casts Dispel Magic.  Unless using a 9th level slot, it will be a DC 19 Spellcasting check.